# Bootstrap Dropdown Disable resizing of button

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

All,
I am trying to disable the resizing of the dropdown button and hide the overflow of text.

My current application has a bootstrap dropdown with some rather large options available for selection. I would like to..

1. Keep the selection button at a specific width.
2. hide any over flow that happens when the user selects a text option large in size.

I can set the width of the button itself, but whenever I select a selection that has a large length, the text overflows outside of the button.

HTML

```
<div class="btn-group dropdown">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Select Values <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Some Very Large Value</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Some Very Large Value Some Very Large Value</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Some Very Large Value Some Very Large Value Some Very Large Value</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            //Makes the selected value show at the top of the dropdown box
            $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
                $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
                $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').val($(this).data('value'));
            });
        });
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e5ry33jL/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:
Find all your li elements and check the length of the text and adjust the length

```
 $('.dropdown-menu').find('li').each(function(){
      console.log( $(this).text().length );
      if($(this).text().length >= 10){
           $(this).text($(this).text().substring(0, 11) + '...')
      }
  });
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/jorge182/e5ry33jL/2/)

Comment: Beautiful, not quit the answer, but i was able to use this approach and apply the substring value to the button. thanks